# What is the opposite of set ff command?

Tags: file

I can set a file format to unix or windows by using:

```
:set ff=unix
```

Is there a way to check the file format ?

Comment: how about `:set ff?`

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2078271/4400820, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12060462/4400820

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set ff?` to check current file format 'interactively'.

If you need to check it in a vimscript, you can use

```
if &ff ==# 'unix'
   "do smth if file format is unix
endif
```

See `:h let-&` and `:h expr-option` for details.